# How to remove the "*" in the file name in aptana 3?

Tags: aptana

My files are like this

```
* hey.js
```

instead of

```
hey.js
```

why, and how to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Aptana Studio, open Preferences, General/Appearence/Label Decorations. Depending on what source repository you use you may want to uncheck "Git Decorator" and/or CVS and/or SVN.

Regards,
Max

Comment: thanks that is! anyway now I know why there are, now I kind of need them thanks

Comment: The asterik seems to be mandatory from what explained by [Michael](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6657152/1577396) in the below post.

Comment: You could still remove the * decoration using what Max suggested.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have the project connected with a GIT or SVN repository?  The * decoration means the local copy of the file is different from the content in the repository.  Once you commit the change and the files are synchronized again, the * will disappear.

Answer (score -3):

If you have a file with a '*' in it, you have to be very careful! The '*' means anyfile.

The following example shows you how to 'escape' this special character and remove a file by that name.

```
bash-3.2$ touch \*
bash-3.2$ touch hey.js
bash-3.2$ ls
*   hey.js
bash-3.2$ rm \*
bash-3.2$ ls
hey.js
bash-3.2$
```

**Be very careful**

if you were to say

```
rm *
```

this would delete **all** files in the directory!!

Comment: I dont really understand your answer: I have the file names of a project with an "*" before the name. Is not the real name of the file, is just something that aptana puts but I dont know why? this happens only in a project... with all files

Comment: @Eljakim, the * in Aptana is not part of the file name, it is just a marking in the list of files. The original question was poorly asked.